# Set WhatId in Task before insert (or update eventually) trigger

Tags: trigger, whatid

We have an APP that create tasks.
Some of them should be related to accounts.
Sometime the whatid is null so the task is linked to nothing.

We have a custom field in task object that contains relevant data relative to account (some phone numbers, actually).

I already have a code that make a map and value the task.

I already have a trigger that call my code.

I can see that, at this point, whatid is valued.

Then the task is created and ... whatid is null !

I looked at other triggers and i add my code at the end of all of them, to be sure noting overrite whatid with null value.

If I run my code on a new Task then insert it, the whatid is correct. So I am assuming that there is a problem with valuing whatid in a trigger.

Is there someone to help me ? :)

Trigger

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert,before update) {
for(Task t : Trigger.new){
    if(
        t.WhatId == NULL
        && !String.isBlank(t.Description)
        && t.Description.contains('<toNumber>')
    ){
        t=BoundMissedCall.boundMissedCall(t);
        system.debug('TaskTrigger : before insert, after boundMissedCall = '+t);
    }    
}}
```

Code :

```
public abstract class BoundMissedCall{
public static Map<String, Account> mapPhoneAccount {get;set;}

static{
    mapPhoneAccount = new Map<String, Account>();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT id, Name, dealership_phone_mecanic__c FROM Account 
                              WHERE dealership_phone_mecanic__c != ''
                             ];
    for(Account a : accounts){
        // for each field in each account, put in the map
        if(!String.isBlank(a.dealership_phone_mecanic__c)) mapPhoneAccount.put(getCorrectPhoneNumber(a.dealership_phone_mecanic__c),a);
    }
}

public static Task boundMissedCall(Task t){
    if(t.WhatId != NULL)                        return t;
    if(String.isBlank(t.Description))           return t;
    if(!t.Description.contains('<toNumber>'))   return t;

    // operations
    Matcher phoneMatcher = Pattern.compile('<toNumber>(.*)</toNumber>').matcher(t.Description);
    if(phoneMatcher.find()){
        String phone = phoneMatcher.group(1);
        system.debug('BoundMissedCall.boundMissedCall() found "'+phone+'" in "'+t.Description+'"');
        phone = getCorrectPhoneNumber(phone);

        Account a = mapPhoneAccount.get(phone);
        if(a != NULL) {
            system.debug('BoundMissedCall.boundMissedCall() found account "'+a.Name+'" with ID "'+a.Id+'" ; setting ...');
            t.WhatId = Id.valueOf(a.id); 
        }
    }
    else{
        system.debug('BoundMissedCall.boundMissedCall() found NO phone in "'+t.Description+'"');
    }
    return t;
}
public static String getCorrectPhoneNumber(String phone){
    phone = phone.replaceAll('[^0-9]','');
    return phone.right(10);
}
```

}

Comment: Share your code as well.

Comment: done (11 more to go!)

Comment: These two conditions can give you a chance to get what id = `null` :- `if(String.isBlank(t.Description))           return t;
    if(!t.Description.contains('<toNumber>'))   return t`

Comment: Of course.But i tested it to check with system.debug that my task has correct value, then has WhatId valued with an id.
But when the trigger is over WhatId is null.

Comment: check for WF and some other trigger which might other developer created in org

Comment: I did, thank for the tip anyway. 
I found the solution by myself just have to wait for 2 days to set it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the answer was simple.

I add another test : **querying my current task record to update my apex instance.**

system.debug(t) -> whatId is null

t = [select ... where id=:t.id]

system.debug(t) -> whatId is valued

The way the currend apex instance is updated or not is a little confusing.

Comment: Make sure you mark your answer as the correct answer.  That way if other people come here they can see clearly that it works, and other people won't waste their time trying to provide you with an answer.